# non-resident: Shares trading in Australia

Tags: non-resident, australia

How can I trade shares in Australia while being a non-resident for tax purposes? Are their any special considerations just for not being in Australia?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no limitations for general investing/trading. You might face issues if you become a majority shareholder in certain companies but I doubt that is your goal.

Comment: Overtaking a company isn't my goal, as a matter of fact, my investment goals are modest and it's I'm trying to learn and understand how things work.

Comment: One more thing for anyone looking at trading shares in Australia while overseas and declaring themselves as non-resident of tax purposes. Avoid shares in real estate companies or companies with massive real estate holdings.